# hr doesn't cover the image

Tags: html, css

Here is a table with 2 rows. The first row contains a `hr`. The second table row has text and an image. Why doesn't the `hr` cover both the image and the text?

```html
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td width="60%" align="center">
                    <p>
                    Every occasion should be a special one!  No matter the event, a custom-designed cake always adds that special something. 

                    Weddings, birthdays, baby showers, an anniversary...  for ANY event, large or small, let me help you celebrate with a delicious and beautifully-designed and decorated cake!

                    Please take a look through my Cake Photo Gallery to see some of the work I've done recently.

                    Anytime Cakes!  Any cake, any style, any time!!

                    Enjoy!

                    ...Andrea
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="40%" align="center">
                    <img src="images/homeimg.jpg">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: This sounds like you should *not* be using tables, as this doesn't contain tabular data. Before you go too far, I wish to stress the utter contempt of using tables for layout

Answer (score 1):

Your second row has two cells, the first one only one. Add `colspan="2"` to the first `td` to make it two columns wide:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">
      <hr class="hr">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td width="60%" align="center">
      <p>
        Every occasion should be a special one! No matter the event, a custom-designed cake always adds that special something. Weddings, birthdays, baby showers, an anniversary... for ANY event, large or small, let me help you celebrate with a delicious and
        beautifully-designed and decorated cake! Please take a look through my Cake Photo Gallery to see some of the work I've done recently. Anytime Cakes! Any cake, any style, any time!! Enjoy! ...Andrea
      </p>
    </td>
    <td width="40%" align="center">
      <img src="images/homeimg.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<td colspan="2"><hr/></td>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colspan` to combine two cols in one col.

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td width="60%" align="center">
                    <p>
                    Every occasion should be a special one!  No matter the event, a custom-designed cake always adds that special something. 

                    Weddings, birthdays, baby showers, an anniversary...  for ANY event, large or small, let me help you celebrate with a delicious and beautifully-designed and decorated cake!

                    Please take a look through my Cake Photo Gallery to see some of the work I've done recently.

                    Anytime Cakes!  Any cake, any style, any time!!

                    Enjoy!

                    ...Andrea
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="40%" align="center">
                    <img src="images/homeimg.jpg">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

For detailed information, you can visit the W3C website: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp